# Implement Notification Service and Content Extension in Dynamic Framework

Tags: swift, notifications, ios10

I have implemented `Extension Notification Service` and `Notification Content Extension` in my demo app and it’s working absolutely fine.

Now, I have to implement it in my framework. Means I’m working on dynamic framework which are support as like chat application. In framework **all screens are created programatically**, Its doesn’t contains any storyboard or XIB.

I have setup all required configuration for `Notification Service Extension` and `Notification Content Extension` same as like my demo app in framework. Everything is same as per my double check on it.

I’m struggling to implement `Notification Service Extension` and `Notification Content Extension`.

Should I need to create `Notification Content` programmatically instead of Storyboard ?
Should I need to add target dependencies ?
What I’m missing ?

> On Dragging notification it's doesn't show me notification content.

Below is the code which I’m currently using for local notification for testing. This code is working in demo app.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func scheduleNotification() {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Notification"
    content.body = "We will remind you that your notification demo is performed well."
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myNotificationCategory"
    content.userInfo = ["Image" as AnyHashable: "https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/img/horse.png"]

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "request", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error to add notification: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Notification added")
        }
    }
}
```

I’m also testing it by debugging, but `didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification)` is also not calling.

I’m stuck ! Please help me? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you using Cocoapods or directly adding .framework?
And is it a closed source framework?

Comment: Directly adding .framework. Framework is private, means not available on GitHub.

Comment: I had a similar issue while integrating a closed source Extension framework. Had resolved the issue by adding static library .a instead of dynamic framework

Comment: Did you try using Static Library in Extension?

Comment: No, I'm not aware about static library extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am getting your point regarding `Notification Service Extension` and `Notification Content Extension` to be added in your private framework. So you framework contains `sharedInstance`, that's why you are not able to implement both extension in your framework because it is not allowed.

So there are solution for that to create one small framework which contains code related to methods of both your extension, this method will be class method. It contains code which populate your notification services.

1. Create new small framework which contains class methods and code related to `Notification Content Extension` and `Notification Service Extension`.
2. Add this framework inside your application with your private framework.
3. Add `Notification Content Extension` and `Notification Service Extension` Target inside your application and implement required method, call relative method from application to your notification framework.

You will get solution using this, but there is one more framework you need to add in your application